# Pattern matching with Kleene star on structure type in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I started playing with Racket pattern matching system recently and got into a problem i can't understand.

If i do:

```
(match (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12)
    [(list _ x y z ...) (list y ': x)])
```

in REPL i get

```
'(3 : 2)
```

as my desired result.

If i do:

```
(match (current-date)
    [(date* _ x y z ...) (list y ': x)])
```

or

```
(match (date* 5 18 13 18 11 2011 5 321 #f 3600 0 "W. Europe Standard Time")
    [(date* _ x y z ...) (list y ': x)])
```

i get this error:

```
match: wrong number for fields for structure date*: expected 12 but got 5 in: (_ x y z ...)
```

i suspect that the Kleene star `...` does not work with struct type for some reason. Why is it so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that what you really want to do is match a subset of the fields in a struct, rather than actually bind the rest of the fields in the struct to (z ...). In this case, you may want to try using the [struct*](http://pre.racket-lang.org/docs/html/reference/match.html?q=struct%2a#(form._((lib._racket/match..rkt)._struct%2a))) match pattern instead.

Here's an example:

```
(match (date* 5 18 13 18 11 2011 5 321 #f 3600 0 "W. Europe Standard Time")
   [(struct* date ([minute x] [hour y])) (list y ': x)])
```

Comment: @ruakh your answer describes *why* it doesn't work. This answer describes *how* to make it work. Both are quite helpful.

Comment: Yes, both are helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

> i suspect that the Kleene star `...` does not work with struct type for some reason.

Correct. The `...` notation, and the related `..k` and `___` and `__k` notations, aren't really a general feature of matching, but rather a specific feature of `list`-matching and `hash-table`-matching and so on. If you examine the formal production in [the documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html), you'll see that some types of subpatterns accept `lvp` (which is defined as either `pat`, or `pat` followed by `...` or one of its friends) in various places, whereas others only accept `pat`.

> Why is it so?

I guess it's simply that `...` is used to translate part of a list or vector or hash-table or whatnot into its own list, and there's no sensible way to do that for a fixed-length struct. It may be worth pointing out that `...` behaves differently for different types — for example, it can be used to extract a list of the keys in a hash-table — so the only reason to support it for structs would be if there were a specific analogous operation that would make sense for structs. I don't think there is one.